# Why isn't my Google Tag Manager event listener being installed?

Tags: google-analytics, dom-events, google-tag-manager

I have a very simple Google Tag Manager trigger that looks like this:

[image: GTM trigger info]

I also have a corresponding tag that uses this trigger.  I have published my container, and the tag shows up when previewing/debugging the container:

[image: Debugging the container]

I also see my link's **id** in the response from GTM.  However, I don't see a GTM listener for click events on my page:

[image]

And, moreover, no GTM action occurs when I click the link.  (The link is a simple **a** tag with `id="currentcustomer"`.)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try unchecking "Wait for tags" and "Check validation"

Comment: Does "simple a tag" include a href attribute with a url ? As nyuen pointed out if you you have "check validation" selected the click will only fire when a valid href is present (so no "#" or javascript links).

Comment: Unchecked both options with no difference, and yes, the **a** element is a simple link with an **href="http://..."**.  There doesn't even seem to be a click listener registered -- shouldn't I need one of those before worrying about things like validation and such?

Comment: The click listener (and link click listener) is now "built in" and does not need to be specified explicitly as you had to in V1.

Comment: @nyuen: correction, turning off both "Wait for tags" and "Check validation" did get the event firing!  If you'd like to post an answer, I'll mark it as such!  (I'd also be very curious *why* these items need to be off..?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck "Wait for Tags" and "Check Validation". When either of these is specified, you get the "Enable When" section of the tag which allows you to specify when the trigger should be listening for the related event. Some good information can be found here: http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/trigger-guide-google-tag-manager/

> Check Validation, when checked, will require that a valid action is propagated to GTM’s listeners. With Link Clicks this means that there’s no event.preventDefault() called by other scripts. In other words, the link click has to be an actual link click, where the action of clicking the link takes the user to another page.

and

> Wait For Tags ensures that all tags that fire on the trigger execute first before proceeding with the action of the event. So if it’s a Link Click trigger, the redirect (or whatever is the action) is halted long enough for all dependent tags to complete execution, after which the action is resumed. Same thing with forms.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think you got it all wrong from the beginning. First - as @nyuen points - turn off the waiting/validation. Then you want to choose "Some clicks" on firing rules, and there you should create your rule to element ID equals currentcustomer.